# Printing in emacs

Tags: emacs, printing, word-wrap

I'm trying to print a page with very long lines in emacs. Someone out there has never heard of the 80 columns rule, and now I'd like to print that file. I'm using the `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` command

When I launch this command, I get lines wrapped in the middle of words. Extremely uncomfortable. But if I use the longlines-mode for examples, I get nice wrapping, but wrong line numbers (lines which wrap get wrong numbers). This problem doesn't occur when I let `ps-print` do the wrapping in the middle of words.

**So how can I tell `ps-print` to wrap at word boundaries and preserve line numbers?**

Thanks!
CFP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched further, but there seems to be no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Before there's a better answer, here is what I'd do: use `fill-region` to hard-wrap and print the buffer, then `undo` to revert if necessary.

The key sequence: <kbd>C-x h</kbd><kbd>M-x fill-region</kbd><kbd>M-x ps-print-buffer-with-face</kbd><kbd>C-/</kbd>.